# How to create Rest Web service client and server

Tags: rest, service, web

Hi I need to use REST web service but not getting how to start. Although I have checked different articles but there is no proper example which tells flow of REST SERVER and REST CLIENT. Is there any good example link which tells how a REST server will be created with php and how this web service will be called with which technique. I need web service to show customers and then update customers using web service as well. I need to create my own web service for my application so I need to create both Rest server and Rest client.

Thanks
Crinch

Answer (score 0):

**REST** isn't a technology, it's a style of **software architecture**

If you want some concrete examples and a simple framework to get started, try [**cherrypy**](http://docs.cherrypy.org/dev/progguide/REST.html), which is a minimal web framework written in python.

This should get you started with a web server that can help you adhere to **REST** design principles.

Comment: Why PHP? It works in _any language_ that has the ability to communicate. It's a _style_, you can't make something work _on REST_. REST is more conceptual than what you imagine it to be, read the **cherrypy** link and all the other pages about it on the web until it makes more sense to you.

Comment: I am sorry if I am not getting understand, I checked link for CHERRYPY but could not get understand.
Actually I have a site developed in plain php, where students records exists, so I want to create a web service which will return these students against course id.
I have already created a web service using nuSOAP(SOAP CLIENT and SOAP SERVER). So I have a same concept of REST(REST CLIENT and REST SERVER).
I am not sure how REST service is created in php and call how to call REST web service.
Also tell me where I am wrong regarding my understanding of REST, I really don't mind it.
Thanks CRINCH

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try PHP REST Data services https://github.com/chaturadilan/PHP-Data-Services